# ¿ Mejor manera de Generar dinámicamente una cantidad determinada de formularios dependiendo del input recogido?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Veréis, tengo una componente `<PreTest />` que se encarga de recoger 3 datos del usuario mediante una dropdown form. Uno es  "número de preguntas", otro "tiempo", y otro "dificultad". El que me interesa en este caso es el primero, el de "numero de preguntas".

Dependiendo si elige "5 preguntas", "10 preguntas", o "15 preguntas", (`items={['5 Preguntas', '10 Preguntas', '15 Preguntas']`) lo que me gustaría es que se generasen la misma cantidad del componente `<Test />` en la siguiente pantalla dependiendo de que ha pinchado el usuario.

Esto en principio no es muy díficl, el problema es que lo tengo diseñado de forma que no se me ocurre muy bien como hacerlo, porque lo tengo estructurado con Rutas y Links:

```js
import React from "react"
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer"
import NavBar from "../NavBar/NavBar"

import "./PreTest.css"

import { Autocomplete, TextInput, Icon } from 'evergreen-ui'

function PreTest(){
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <main>
        <div class="viewport-main">
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="title-create">
                        <h2>Personaliza tu Test</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="icons-create-container">
                        <div>
                        <Icon icon="applications" color="success" size={100} />
                                                                                    <Autocomplete
                                                        title=""
                                                        
                                                        onChange={changedItem => console.log(changedItem)}
                                                        items={['5 Preguntas', '10 Preguntas', '15 Preguntas']}
                                                        >
                                                        {(props) => {
                                                            const { getInputProps, getRef, inputValue, openMenu } = props
                                                            return (
                                                            <TextInput
                                                                placeholder="Número de Preguntas"
                                                                value={inputValue}
                                                                
                                                                innerRef={getRef}
                                                                {...getInputProps({
                                                                onFocus: () => {
                                                                    openMenu()
                                                                }
                                                                })}
                                                            />
                                                            )
                                                        }}
                                                        </Autocomplete>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <Icon icon="time" color="warning" size={100} />
                            <Autocomplete
                                                        title="Activar Temporizador"
                                                        onChange={changedItem => console.log(changedItem)}
                                                        items={['3 Minutos', '5 Minutos', '10 Minutos']}
                                                        >
                                                        {(props) => {
                                                            const { getInputProps, getRef, inputValue, openMenu } = props
                                                            return (
                                                            <TextInput
                                                                placeholder="Tiempo límite"
                                                                value={inputValue}
                                                                innerRef={getRef}
                                                                {...getInputProps({
                                                                onFocus: () => {
                                                                    openMenu()
                                                                }
                                                                })}
                                                            />
                                                            )
                                                        }}
                                                        </Autocomplete>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <Icon icon="lightbulb" color="info" size={100} />
                            <Autocomplete
                                                        title="Indicar Dificultad"
                                                        onChange={changedItem => console.log(changedItem)}
                                                        items={['Fácil', 'Medio', 'Difícil']}
                                                        >
                                                        {(props) => {
                                                            const { getInputProps, getRef, inputValue, openMenu } = props
                                                            return (
                                                            <TextInput
                                                                placeholder="Dificultad estimada"
                                                                value={inputValue}
                                                                innerRef={getRef}
                                                                {...getInputProps({
                                                                onFocus: () => {
                                                                    openMenu()
                                                                }
                                                                })}
                                                            />
                                                            )
                                                        }}
                                                        </Autocomplete>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </main>
         <Footer />                                              
        </div>
    )
}

export default PreTest
```

```js
import React from "react"
import { Pane, Label, Textarea, FilePicker } from 'evergreen-ui'
import "./Test.css"
import FooterTest from "../Footer/FooterTest"
import NavBar from "../NavBar/NavBar"

function Test(){
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <main>
        <div class="viewport-main">
            <div class="main-containerTest">
                <div class="title-create">
                    <div class="half">
                                <Pane>
                                <Label
                                    htmlFor="textarea-2"
                                    marginBottom={2}
                                    display="block"
                                >
                                    Respuesta 1
                                </Label>
                                <Textarea width={400}
                                    id="textarea-2"
                                    placeholder="Escribe aquí tu repsuesta"
                                />
                    </Pane>
                    <Pane>
                                <Label
                                    htmlFor="textarea-2"
                                    marginBottom={2}
                                    display="block"
                                >
                                    Respuesta 2
                                </Label>
                                <Textarea width={400}
                                    id="textarea-2"
                                    placeholder="Escribe aquí tu repsuesta"
                                />
                    </Pane>
                    </div>
                    <div class="half">
                    <Pane>
                                <Label 
                                    htmlFor="textarea-2"
                                    marginBottom={2}
                                    display="block"
                                >
                                    Respuesta 3
                                </Label>
                                <Textarea width={400}
                                    id="textarea-2"
                                    placeholder="Escribe aquí tu repsuesta"
                                />
                    </Pane>
                    <Pane>
                                <Label
                                    htmlFor="textarea-2"
                                    marginBottom={2}
                                    display="block"
                                >
                                    Respuesta 4
                                </Label>
                                <Textarea width={400}
                                    id="textarea-2"
                                    placeholder="Textarea placeholder..."
                                />
                    </Pane>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="title-create">
                <FilePicker marginLeft={92} marginTop={50} multiple width={"50%"}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      <FooterTest />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/entrar" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/registro" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/personaliza-test" component={PreTest} />
        <Route path="/crear-test" component={Test} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Cómo veis, una manera que se me ha ocurrido sería en la ruta "/crear-test" podría facilmente renderizar el componente `<Test />` la cantidad de veces que el usuario ha elegido el formulario. Pero claro estaría toda en esa ruta, en una sola pantalla. Mi intención es que cada `<Test />` aparezca en una pantalla diferente. Es decir, cada vez que se pincha el botón "siguiente" que ahí en el componente `<Test />` te avance a la siguiente recogida de datos. Así hasta, por ejemplo, 10 veces si el usuario eligió 10 en el dropdown.

Por ejemplo se puede generar dinámicamente rutas diferentes sin saber realmente cuantas van a ser necesarias hasta que el usuario elija en el dropdown? "/crear-test01", "/crear-test02", "/crear-test03" ...etc